# People to follow if I am interested in wide-angle photography

Tags: digital, wide-angle

I am experimenting with wide-angle lens but not able to find suitable blogs and images to improve my perspective. I want to follow some people and understand their work who are famous in this field i.e. taking wide-angle pictures.

If anyone has suggestions, it will be helpful for me.

Thank you.

Comment: This is an open-ended discussion, along the lines of http://photo.stackexchange.com/faq#dontask. Can you think of a way to narrow this down so that there could reasonably be one canonical answer to the question?

Answer (score 3):

A wide angle lens is just a tool.  I would expect most photographers would use a variety of lenses, so following or studying specific photographers might prove fruitless.

I guess wide angle photography is most common in landscapes, photojournalism, travel and often street photography.

You could start with some masters in genres which make more use of wide angles:

- landscapes (Ansel Adams, Galen Rowell)
- street (Henri Cartier-Bresson, Jay Maisel)
- photojournalism ( Robert Capa, Philip Jones Griffiths)

[National Geographic](http://photography.nationalgeographic.com/photography/) produces a rich variety of all sorts of photographs, environmental portraits, landscapes, nature.  Much of it utilizing wide angles. (there is even a book! - see comment from Itai below)

You could search on [500px](http://500px.com/) and [Flickr](http://www.flickr.com/) for "wide angle", or browse through categories such as landscapes.

Comment: I'll second National Geographic but there an easier way. I bought the book [Wide-Angle](http://www.amazon.com/Wide-Angle-National-Geographic-Collectors/dp/B00B558SS0) filled with, well, wide-angle images. Its an amazing value considering the quality of images and the low cost of the book.

Comment: @Itai - I plan to buy that book now, does it have any techniques and suggestions mentioned on how to leverage the use of Wide angle lens?

Comment: @sat - No, it is purely a showcase. So you learn by analyzing images yourself. The interesting part is that I've gone over the book a few times and always notice new interactions between the elements. Most NG images have a lot of layers to them.